# Abrir PDF con opción para imprimir directamente

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Buen día, estoy trabajando con `rotativa` para generar un pdf, cosa que no me da problema. llevo rato investigando una manera de imprimir directamente el pdf sin mostrar el preview del pdf en el navegador, pero al parecer no hay manera posible. así que, en vez de eso, busco si existe alguna manera de que, al abrir el pdf en la ventana, se abra también la ventana para imprimir. el sistema será utilizado sólo en google chorme, así que necesito hacerlo compatible con ello. actualmente genero el PDF de la siguiente manera:

```
public Rotativa.MVC.ActionAsPdf HojaPedidoSimple(string selectedProvider, string sucursal)
        {
            return new Rotativa.MVC.ActionAsPdf("HojaPedido", new { selectedProvider = selectedProvider,sucursal=sucursal,pdf = true });
        }
```

Manera en la que llamo a ese PDF con javascript:

```
 url = "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("PrintHojaPedido",new {@selectedProvider="4a5b6c",@sucursal="1a2b3c" }))";
                url = url.replace("1a2b3c", SelectedSucursal);
                url = url.replace("4a5b6c", selectedProvider);
                var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
                win.focus();
```

es posible hacer lo que deseo? no he encontrado nada al respecto en interntet.

Comment: Me parece que por motivos de seguridad eso escapa a las posibilidades de automatización.

Comment: imprimir directamente no es posible, eso me apareció en lo que investigue, pero es posible manipular la vista del pdf para que, al menos te abra la pantalla de imprimir de chrome?

Comment: Hasta donde me da la memoria, eso está fuera del alcance de los desarrolladores, eso tiene que ser un proceso por efecto del usuario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes abrir la opcion de imprimir un ventana del navegador con la función `window.print()` y si guardas en una variable la ejecucion de `window.open()` puedes utilizar el metodo `print()` en esa variable.

yo lo pondria antes del `win.focus();`

Javascript

```
let win = window.open()

win.print();
```

Comment: Por favor lee [answer]

Comment: Perdon es tarde y me ha entrado la pereza xD

Comment: hahaha, hermano, aquí todos colaboramos con la buena calidad del sitio, dale una patada espartana a esa pereza limitante. Gracias por la respuesta :D